# Sentinel-1 SAR Level 1 Data

Tags: metadata, sentinel-1, sar

From where I can find the satellite Metadata ( satellite position vector, velocity) for the corresponding SAR Level 1 image?

I have tried to look but didn't find the source to download these files.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation on Sentinel-1 Level 1 products](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-1-sar/products-algorithms/level-1-product-formatting):

"Sentinel data products are distributed using a Sentinel-specific variation of the Standard Archive Format for Europe (SAFE) specification. The SAFE format has been designed to act as a common format for archiving and conveying data within ESA Earth Observation archiving facilities. SAFE was recommended for the harmonization of the GMES missions by the GMES Product Harmonisation Study.

The Sentinel-SAFE format wraps a folder containing image data in a binary data format and product metadata in XML. This flexibility allows the format to be scalable enough to represent all levels of Sentinel products.

A Sentinel product refers to a directory folder that contains a collection of information. It includes:

- **a manifest.safe file which holds the general product information in XML**
  subfolders for measurement data sets containing image data in various binary formats
- preview folder containing quicklooks in PNG format, Google Earth overlays in KML format and HTML preview files
- an annotation folder containing the product metadata in XML as well as calibration data
- a support folder containing the XML schemes describing the product XML

The data delivered is packaged as a file structure containing a manifest file in XML format listing general product metadata and subfolders for measurement data, annotations, previews and support files (the number of subfolders is reduced for raw data).

...

**The manifest file is an XML file containing the mandatory product metadata common to all Sentinel-1 products.**"

Data products should be available from the [Copernicus Data Space Ecosystem](https://dataspace.copernicus.eu/#/)

Comment: Could you also provide the website from where I can download the data?